# How to stop VIM dereferencing symlinks?

Tags: vim, symlink

My VIM doesn't follow usual particles and tries to dereference symlinks. For example, when I do `$ cd` to symlink in any shell, I don't expect it to change current working directory to the actual place where the symlink points to.

Any shell behavior:

```
$ ls -l
mydir -> /some/super/long/and/ugly/path
$ cd ./mydir
$ pwd
<fullpath>/mydir
```

VIM behavior:

```
:cd ~/mydir
:pwd
/some/super/long/and/ugly/path
```

This makes impossible to do things like `:cd ../otherdir`, because there is no `/some/super/long/and/ugly/otherdir`.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/711001/1476061) answer please.

Comment: So there is no solution :( too bad